# Python Pandas - How to write in a specific column in an Excel Sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am having trouble updating an Excel Sheet using pandas by writing new values in it. I already have an existing frame df1 that reads the values from MySheet1.xlsx. so this needs to either be a new dataframe or somehow to copy and overwrite the existing one.

The spreadsheet is in this format:

[image]

I have a python list: values_list = [12.34, 17.56, 12.45]. My goal is to insert the list values under Col_C header vertically. It is currently overwriting the entire dataframe horizontally, without preserving the current values.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col_C': values_list})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('excelfile.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='MySheet1')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['MySheet1']
```

How to get this end result? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Below I've provided a fully reproducible example of how you can go about modifying an existing .xlsx workbook using pandas and the openpyxl module [(link to Openpyxl Docs)](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

First, for demonstration purposes, I create a workbook called test.xlsx:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
wb  = writer.book
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col_A': [1,2,3,4],
                  'Col_B': [5,6,7,8],
                  'Col_C': [0,0,0,0],
                  'Col_D': [13,14,15,16]})

df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

This is the Expected output at this point:

[image: Expected Output after first section of code]

In this second part, we load the existing workbook ('test.xlsx') and modify the third column with different data.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'Col_C': [9, 10, 11, 12]})
wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')

ws = wb['Sheet1']

for index, row in df_new.iterrows():
    cell = 'C%d'  % (index + 2)
    ws[cell] = row[0]

wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

This is the Expected output at the end:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. This worked for me. Can you please elaborate on this line: cell = 'C%d'  % (index + 2)? Is there anyway i could replace C with the actual header name, in my case Col_C? Thanks!

Comment: So for the `cell = 'C%d' % (index + 2)` it resolves to the cell reference - that is when index = 0 then `cell = 'C2'` and I don't think you should change that.  You could change `ws[cell] = row[0]` to `ws[cell] = row['Col_C']` and it would work.  Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: @patrickjlong1 Is there a way to find the active cell in an excel sheet you wanna read? Or a way to find the active sheet among multiple excel sheets??

Comment: @Eswar.  A particular cell - Not that I know of.  For a particular row, you could use the usecols parameter on `pandas.read_excel()` to select a particular column by name or location.

Comment: I have a noobie question, wb means workbook? ws means worksheet? , but for the life of me I dont get what df means, I've seen it some other places. Can you please tell me?

Comment: @Allex Radu, in this example the df object is a [Pandas Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion, the easiest solution is to read the excel as a panda's dataframe, and modify it and write out as an excel. So for example:

Comments:

Import pandas as pd.
Read the excel sheet into pandas data-frame called.
Take your data, which could be in a list format, and assign it to the column you want. (just make sure the lengths are the same). Save your data-frame as an excel, either override the old excel or create a new one.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
ExcelDataInPandasDataFrame = pd.read_excel("./YourExcel.xlsx")
YourDataInAList = [12.34,17.56,12.45]
ExcelDataInPandasDataFrame ["Col_C"] = YourDataInAList
ExcelDataInPandasDataFrame .to_excel("./YourNewExcel.xlsx",index=False)
```

Comment: The caveat here is that you lose any formulas that might exist in other columns of the sheet you are overwriting.