# How can turn <Cell 'Sheet'.A2> to only 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

i have problem with openpyxl. My code is working but i can not figure out for saving value to excel

my code is

```
def get_title(link):
    global list2
    driver = create_driver()
    driver.get(link)
    source = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
    title = source.select_one("title").text
    print(f"{link}: '{title}'")
    
    for row in ws.rows:
        if row[0].value == link:
            print(row)
            # ws.cell(row=???, column=2).value = title
            # wb.save("site.xlsx")
```

and it prints out

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=2&oq=2&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59l2j0i271l2j69i60l2j69i61.623j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8: '2 - Google search'
(<Cell 'Sheet'.A2>, <Cell 'Sheet'.B2>)
https://www.google.com/search?q=6&oq=6&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i271l3j69i60l3.3687j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8: '6 - Google search'
(<Cell 'Sheet'.A1>, <Cell 'Sheet'.B1>)
```

what i want to do is i want to save title to B column in excel but i don't know how to do that

Comment: This is a bit old, but it should get you making progress using the pandas library to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681392/python-pandas-how-to-write-in-a-specific-column-in-an-excel-sheet

Comment: thanks but it won't work for me i need to match url and titles in excel. And if i turn in to pandas i need to change many codes

Comment: Not just `row[1].value = title` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            for row in ws.iter_rows(0):
                for cell in row:
                    if cell.value == "test":
                        ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=2).value = "test"
                        wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

this one fix my problem