# How to parse a JSON/dict-like value from an Excel sheet and copy over to another column?

Tags: python, excel

I have an Excel sheet, where data is entered in this format:

```
{"id":"03CD2B3C22558D83","imp":6667, floor:7777}
```

How can I in python read and extract a certain value of an attribute in Excel, and copy this on another column? For example, I want to obtain the value 6667.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Read [How to read data form excel sheets in Python](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-python-parse-spreadsheet-data/) and [How to write data to a specific cell in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681392/python-pandas-how-to-write-in-a-specific-column-in-an-excel-sheet)

Comment: Is that entire JSON/dict-like value entered in one cell? I'm assuming `floor` is a typo, and it's actually a string `"floor"` like `"id"` and `"imp"`

Answer (score 1):

This works, simple and no error checking:

[image]

```
MID(A1,FIND("imp",A1,1)+5,4)
```

Comment: I think the question was asking for a Python solution: "*how i can in python to read and extract certain the value*". It was also tagged with python.

Comment: @GinoMempin if you look it is **also** tagged with excel, so I was being generous.

Comment: @GinoMempin and given the poor use of English it is difficult to be absolutely sure - as pointed out in another comment.

Comment: @GinoMempin and some other user may find the excel answer useful in the future - part of the reason people post on here, or don’t you understand that?

Comment: @GinoMempin So where is your python solution? At least I was positive with my post…

Answer (score 0):

You can use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to work with Excel files.
The [openpyxl tutorial](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) should help you get started on how to use it.

I'll assume this kind of value:

```
{"id":"03CD2B3C22558D83","imp":6667, floor:7777}
```

is stored on each cell, like this:

[image: screenshot of Excel file with cells A1-A5 with JSON string values]

Using openpyxl, you first read the value of each cell **as a string**.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Assume Excel file named "test.xlsx"
# Assume sheet named "Sheet1"
wb = load_workbook(filename="test.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

# Get the value of cell A1 - A5
# In openpyxl, rows/columns start at index 1
for row_idx in range(1, 6):
    cell = ws.cell(row=row_idx, column=1)
    print(type(cell.value), cell.value)
```

```
$ python test.py
<class 'str'> {"id":"03CD2B3C22558D83","imp":6667, floor:7777}
<class 'str'> {"id":"1111111111111111","imp":1111, floor:1000}
<class 'str'> {"id":"2222222222222222","imp":2222, floor:2000}
<class 'str'> {"id":"3333333333333333","imp":3333, floor:3000}
<class 'str'> {"id":"4444444444444444","imp":4444, floor:4000
```

Then, once you can access each cell value, convert it to a regular Python dictionary.

Now, normally you can use [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)'s [`.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to convert. But the problem is that the JSON string is malformed, it's missing double-quotes `""` around `floor`. You can check on https://jsonlint.com/:

[image: JSONLint error]

It would have worked nicely if `floor` was wrapped in double-quotes:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = '{"id":"03CD2B3C22558D83","imp":6667, "floor":7777}'
>>> d = json.loads(s)
>>> d["imp"]
6667
```

If you have no control over how the data was written to the Excel file, check the workarounds for [parsing a somewhat wrong JSON with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1931454/2745495). A quick workaround I usually use is the [`dirtyjson` library](https://github.com/codecobblers/dirtyjson):

```
>>> import dirtyjson
>>> s = '{"id":"03CD2B3C22558D83","imp":6667, floor:7777}'
>>> d = dirtyjson.loads(s)
>>> d
AttributedDict([('id', '03CD2B3C22558D83'), ('imp', 6667), ('floor', 7777)])
>>> d = dict(d)
>>> d
{'id': '03CD2B3C22558D83', 'imp': 6667, 'floor': 7777}
>>> d["imp"]
6667
```

So, assuming there are no typos in the example data, let's use `dirtyjson` to convert to a dict, then access the `imp` value:

```
import dirtyjson
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Assume Excel file named "test.xlsx"
# Assume sheet named "Sheet1"
wb = load_workbook(filename="test.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

# For each value of cell A1 - A5
#   Convert the value to a dictionary
for row_idx in range(1, 6):  # In openpyxl, rows/columns start at index 1
    cell = ws.cell(row=row_idx, column=1)
    data = dict(dirtyjson.loads(cell.value))
    print(data, data["imp"])
```

```
$ python test.py
{'id': '03CD2B3C22558D83', 'imp': 6667, 'floor': 7777} 6667
{'id': '1111111111111111', 'imp': 1111, 'floor': 1000} 1111
{'id': '2222222222222222', 'imp': 2222, 'floor': 2000} 2222
{'id': '3333333333333333', 'imp': 3333, 'floor': 3000} 3333
{'id': '4444444444444444', 'imp': 4444, 'floor': 4000} 4444
```

Finally, simply write the value to another column. Let's assume, you want to copy it over to the `B` column on the same row. You can pick any other column or cell, just remember that openpyxl processes cell rows and columns with 1-index notation, so for the `B` column, that would be `column=2`.

```
import dirtyjson
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Assume Excel file named "test.xlsx"
# Assume sheet named "Sheet1"
wb = load_workbook(filename="test.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

# For each value of cell A1 - A5
#   Convert the value to a dictionary
#   Write the "imp" value to the B column
for row_idx in range(1, 6):  # In openpyxl, rows/columns start at index 1
    cell = ws.cell(row=row_idx, column=1)
    data = dict(dirtyjson.loads(cell.value))
    ws.cell(
        row=row_idx,
        column=2,  # B
        value=data["imp"],
    )

# DO NOT FORGET TO SAVE AND CLOSE WHEN DONE!
# Also, keep the file closed when writing
wb.save(filename="test_output.xlsx")
wb.close()
```

[image: sample output Excel file with values written to B column]

---

Tested with

- Python 3.9.10
- openpyxl 3.0.9
- dirtyjson 1.0.7
- macOS 10.15.7 with Microsoft Excel for Mac 16.6.6