# how to select two specefied columns of two excel files and insert them in order, to a new excel file python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

```
i want to select two specefied columns of two different excel files and then insert them in order in a new excel file
```

i have two excel files : excel1 ,excel2

and each of these excel files have columns named : R ,KPI

I want to select from each of these excel files , the selected columns(R,KPI), and then insert them in order into a new excel file named : excel3 how that is possible? thanks

i tried to write it with FOR loop < but it only insert columns of one of the excel files to the new excel files.

```
#reading excel files from computer
excelpath1=''+input(''+r"Insert your Excel path(HIGH):")
excelpath2=''+input(''+r"Insert your Excel path(LOW):")
excelpath1=excelpathH.replace('"', '')
excelpath2=excelpathL.replace('"', '')
df1=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(excelpathH), engine='openpyxl' )
df2=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(excelpathL), engine='openpyxl' )

#ASK FROM USER THAT FOR MAKING A NEW EXCEL FILE, CHOOSE A NAME
new_excel_by_user=str(input("write the name of your new EXCEL file:"))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(new_excel_by_user+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
dfn=pd.DataFrame()
#LOOP IN EXCEL1 AND EXCEL2 FOR CHOOSING COLUMNS THAT MUST BE WRITTEN IN NEW EXCEL FILE
for i in df1 :
df1.to_excel(writer,columns=['b', 'KPIVALUE'], sheet_name = "Sheet1")
for j in df2 :
 df2.to_excel(writer,columns=['AL'], sheet_name = "Sheet1")
```

the problem is columns from excel1 cpied to new excel , but column of excel2 doesnt

Comment: Can you please update the question, with more details and what are things you want to do, data example

Comment: sure, but kind of details you want me to explain?

Comment: name of column, data schema and what you have tried from your end

Comment: Size of the file will also be good thing to include

Comment: columns : R , KPI

Comment: EXCEL FILES : excel1 , excel 2 , excel 3

Comment: both excel1 and excel 2 , have columns named R and KPI

Comment: what i want :  i want to have a each column of each excel file in a new excel file  named : excel3

Comment: Where are the excel 1 and excel 2 data ? can you include sample data?

Comment: they are two excel file on my computer , i give the address and python read them, code added to the question

Comment: It is so confusing if without seeing the data what columns in which file you are talking about

Comment: Please follow this -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: codes added, check them please

Comment: Your problem seems to be very easy but you need to either post sample data picture or few rows

Comment: please check the question , i added all the codes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas - How to write in a specific column in an Excel Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681392/python-pandas-how-to-write-in-a-specific-column-in-an-excel-sheet)

Comment: Hi. Indentation seems off here. Just a typo from copy-paste? Anyways, regarding [ask], it looks like you should decompose the steps and present us with only the one that poses a problem. Is reading files ok? then skip that and directly give us the dataframes. To post part of a dataframe for [mre], give us the output of `print(df.to_dict())`

Comment: the link you wrote , helped. thannks and it has no relation to indentations

Answer (score 0):

When using pandas, you can merge both dataframes in to one, after that just change column names:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(excelpathH), engine='openpyxl' )
df2=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(excelpathL), engine='openpyxl' )

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='cross')
```

If both excel files have same column names, new dataframe will have colmns named:

R_x, KPI_x, R_y, KPI_y

Just change names of those columns, eg.:

```
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'R_x': 'R_excel1', 'KPI_x': 'KPI_excel1', 'R_y': 'R_excel2', 'KPI_y': 'KPI_excel2'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: THANKS LOTBUT IF I WANT ONLY TO SPECEFIX COLUMNS FROM EACH EXCEL FILE, WHAT SHOULD I DO?

Comment: BECAUSE 'MERGE' SELECTS ALL OF THE COLUMNS OF EACH EXCEL FILE, NOT THOSE I WANT

Comment: then just modify your df to have only 2 columsn like: df1 = df1[['R', 'KPI']] etc. after that perform merge